# share a photo on facebook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, webforms

How can I share a photo from my desktop to Facebook? I copied this code from the internet, it worked, but I am not sure how to change what is written here to share the photo I already added to the webform

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#share_button').click(function (e) { 
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: 'jQuery Dialog',
link: 'http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/authors/raj1979/raj-kumar.aspx',
picture: 'http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/AuthorImage/raj1979.gif',
caption: 'This article demonstrates how to use the jQuery dialog feature in ASP.Net.',
description: 'First of all make a new website in ASP.Net and add a new stylesheet and add .js files and put images in the images folder and make a reference to the page.',
message: 'hello'
}); }); });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? Any error you see?

Comment: no Sir just the (#506) Duplicate status message error i can ignore it for now, no error mentioned, i just need to share the photo i already added to my webpage, and the code here will just share the link provided by the developer i copied the code from...NB: i am a fresh programmer please excuse my limited knowledge